# Using JW Player with iphone, audio files will only play in quicktime player

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, jwplayer

I created some custom controls to handle playback of an mp3 file in JW Player and hid the player. The controls work well on everything but iPhone. When I show the player, open in iphone, and click the JW Player play button, it opens the track in Quicktime and begins playing. So, apparently the iPhone will only play the track in its own player rather than through the JW Player. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an example to test? 

From the JW Player site: JW Player supports AAC (.aac, .m4a, and .f4a), MP3, and Vorbis (.ogg and .oga) audio formats. During playback of audio files, your poster image will remain visible. If you don’t want your poster image to show, you can set up a very narrow player containing only the control bar. We call this our “audio mode”.

Comment: I don't have an example up since it contains sensitive information, but I had also tried the .aac and .m4a formats with no luck. Ethan's comment below seems to indicate that it's not possible to control the audio programmatically since it pops up in QT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an iPhone with auto, the full screen QT player will appear. On an iPad, it plays inline.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "an iPhone with auto?"

Comment: I mean basically if you use an iPhone, it will always show in the native full screen QT player.

Comment: Is there anyway at all to play mp3s on a iPhone using jwplayer that won't trigger the QT player? I thought this problem was solved? E.g. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/javascript-interaction/25882/ios-audio-playback-issue-with-quicktime/

Comment: Could one play hidden videos that have the same audio track? would that trigger the quicktime player?

Comment: It will always trigger the qt player. If you really want inline audio, I would suggest using an <audio> tag.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The audio would always open in QT player full screen. After a little investigation I found that JW player currently uses a html5 video tag for audio and video. My solution as per the below was to use some jquery to change the tag type. The iPhone allows html5 audio to play inline.

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer(player);
playerInstance.setup({
    file: filepath,
    preload: "auto",
    primary: "html5",
    flashplayer: "/scripts/jwplayer-7.5.0/jwplayer.flash.swf?d=20160801",
    repeat: true,
    autostart: false,
    events: {
        onError: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
});
playerInstance.setVolume(50);
playerInstance.onReady(function () {
    $("#" + player + " .jw-media")
        .each(function () {
            var audioHtml = $(this).html();
            audioHtml = audioHtml
                .replace(/<video/g, '<audio')
                .replace(/<\/video>/g, '</audio>');
            $(this).html(audioHtml);
        });
});
```